# Error when using Invoke-Expression to install elasticsearch

Tags: powershell

I am having trouble Installing Elasticsearch via powershell :

```
Invoke-Expression -command "C:\elk\elasticsearch-6.2.1\bin\service install"
```

and this is the error it throws:

> C:\elk\elasticsearch-6.2.1\bin\service : The term 'C:\elk\elasticsearch-6.2.1\bin\service' is not recognized as the name of a cmdlet, function, script file, or operable program. Check the spelling of the name, or if a path was included, verify that the path is correct and try again.

I am sure im missing something, please help.

Comment: `get-help Invoke-Expression -examples`. Check this and you might find out what you are missing!

Comment: Simply extract the zip file and execute `.\bin\elasticsearch-service.bat install` to install the service. Might be a good idea to re-read the [install instructions](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/zip-windows.html) so you know what you're trying to do first.

Comment: silly mistake, thanks James